# Advantages of string_view literals vs string literals in simple scenarios

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

So I am reading code written for newer versions of CPP and frequently see string_view literals used almost exclusively, even in simple use cases.

For example:

```
std::cout<<"Hello world"sv<<std::endl;
```

Is there any particular reason for that? It is obviously not about storage duration, because string_view only wraps string literal. Do the string_view's have lower overhead or something?

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: It is more to move from pointer semantics to object and move semantics (with close or zero overhead). They also keep track of bounds better then raw char*. You can pass them as objects to functions and return them (be careful they still don't own the data so they could refer to local data on stack). Also nice, they work on subparts of a string without having to insert '\0' characters to denote their end. All in all I mostly stopped using const char* as a result.

Comment: One more advantage : operator== is defined for string_view and will compare content of the string view. Where comparing to const char* might return false even if the content they point to is the same (at different addresses ofcourse).

Comment: Read this https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1217154594/cplusplus-stdstring_view-for-better-performance-an-example-use-case and be aware of this https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/11/09/pass-string-view-by-value/

Comment: @PepijnKramer so it is mostly about "best practices" then? While I do understand the advantages, it is sort of irritating seeing an "sv" suffix after every string everywhere.

Comment: In a way not really, this is another tool in your toolbox. You still can have a std::string_view on a function and pass it a string literal. Like always you need to chose your types when you design.  As for the "sv" suffix, that is more a getting used to thing I guess.  And I just find things like string_view, span and std::array work much more consistently then their "C" style pointer counterparts.

Answer (score 4):

Shown example do not introduce any significant gains.

The only case where there might be a difference is when you use zero inside literal:

```cpp
    std::cout << "zerro \0insde"sv << std::endl;
    std::cout << "zerro \0insde" << std::endl;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/54v1a518f

Comment: For completeness' sake, `"zerro \0inside"s` would work as well in this case (requiring the explicit `using namespace std::string_literals`, or the more general `using namespace std::literals`.)

Comment: Better is to compare std::string_view f() { return "foo"; } with std::string_view f() { return "foo"sv; }

The string_view literal has its length computed at compile time.

Comment: @Andrew https://godbolt.org/z/sWKsfeoe9

Comment: @MarekR - Yes. Note to self: "don't forget to turn on the optimizer."

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `std::string` can be costly as it often involves allocating memory dynamically. When the cost of creating a `std::string` is a concern, using `const char*` and length parameters as an alternative may reduce the expense, but it can also make the code less readable and harder to use.

`std::string_view`, introduced in C++17, is a non-owning, read-only reference to a sequence of characters. Its purpose is to provide a way for functions to take a read-only reference to an object resembling `std::string`, without needing to specify the exact type. The downside of using a `const std::string&` in such cases is that it creates a `std::string` object.

`std::string_view` is a lightweight object that holds a pointer to the original string, and its length. Because it doesn't own the memory it points to, it doesn't need to manage the memory itself, which can make it more efficient than `std::string`. However, it can also have more overhead in certain cases. For example, if a `std::string_view` is frequently copied, it will need to create a new object each time, which can be more expensive than copying a `std::string`.

Additionally, because it doesn't own the memory it points to, it must ensure that the original string remains valid as long as the `std::string_view` is being used, which can also add some overhead.

P.S. be careful and use it with caution, as you do not own it

Additionally really great article to read https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/11/09/pass-string-view-by-value/

Comment: *"if a std::string_view is frequently copied, it will need to create a new object each time, which can be more expensive than copying a std::string"* I can't imagine copying one being more expensive than copying `std::string`. *"must ensure that the original string remains valid as long as the std::string_view is being used, which can also add some overhead"* That's a programmer's concern, what overhead do you mean?

Comment: `std::string_view` might be *twice* as expensive to copy as a `const char *`! But the benefit is never having to traverse the string to know when it ends.

Comment: Suggest changing _"...it points to, __it__ must ensure..."_ to _"...it points to, __you__ must ensure..."_ as `std::string_view` has no effect on the lifetime of object it references.  Leaving a dangling mess if the user does not manage lifetimes correctly.

Comment: Why would copying a `string_view` be expensive if it's just a pointer and a length? What do you mean it has to create a new object? Does it allocate something on the heap when copied?